# Can't access files in linked storage folder in laravel by url

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I have an app that saves pdfs to the Laravel storage folder that must then be made public.

I linked the `/storage` folder in laravel's root to public as per laravel instructions by using: `php artisan storage:link`

I'm having a confusing issue where I can't figure out how to access the files in that storage folder via URL.

When it comes to path to those files, they are now located in storage here:

`/storage/app/public/`

And the linked path to that same folder is

`/public/storage/`

if I put a test file in `/public/` i can access it by going to `localhost:3000/file.pdf`

However if I try to put a file in `/public/storage/`, I get a 404 when I go to `localhost:3000/storage/file.pdf` and I can't figure out why!

The files are being correctly linked, as I can find them both in `/public/storage` and in `/storage/app/public` folders, the content of those folders match.

When I run `dd( public_path() );` I get: `"/home/vagrant/code/project/public"`

When I run `dd( storage_path() );` I get: `"/home/vagrant/code/project/storage"`

I have the following in my `filesystems.php` file:

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Which seems to mean that the files being saved to storage should be saved to `/storage/app/public` which is true, and that the url should be `localhost:3000/storage` which seems not to be working! What am I missing?

Comment: delete shortcut storage folder from /public/ and run php artisan storage:link again and try

Comment: @JohnLobo Didn't help, still get a 404. Also triple checked that the file name is correct, copy-pasted it

Comment: are you sure you have files in the path of storage/app/public/file.pdf

Comment: yes I have some folders in /storage/app/public as well but i put the test file directly in the /storage/app/public folder for testing

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your laravel project is running on localhost:3000 and not on localhost:80?

I am wondering because usually localhost:3000 is used by some sort of node.js (vue/nuxt.js) application. If so your laravel backend part should be accessible via api or on localhost/storage/file.pdf (if file is directly under app/public folder).

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it is on :3000, all the pages and stuff work fine it's just getting the URL of items in storage that isn't working

Comment: Ok then. Have you tried localhost:3000/storage/storage/file.pdf while having the file in /storage/app/public/storage/file.php ?

Can you post your apache .conf file?